# Is it prefered to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in the website?

Tags: php, include-path, document-root

Do you think it is preferred to use **`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`** in website's `include` statements? Is it supported everywhere without any problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many frameworks use `dirname(__FILE__)` to work out the application path based on a known file, usually the index.php

In the Zend Framework, they use the following to define the application path, which is then used everywhere in the app:

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application');
```

Comment: In PHP 5.3 you can just use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer relative paths: `include("../../some/other/path.php")`  Whenever I create a directory, I know exactly how my directory tree is setup, and it doesn't matter whether there is a document root or anything else available.

Furthermore, there are some cases where `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` may not work (eg, I have seen people have issues with it on IIS).