# PHP shared hosting interpretation of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: php, apache, versioning, document-root

I've been using a PHP script to have automated versioning on files, and in it, it uses `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get the path to locate the file.

It works most of the time, but every so often, the server(shared hosting) seems to misinterpret the path.

It SHOULD ALWAYS be: `/home/username/public_html`

But sometimes it comes out as: `/usr/local/apache/htdocs`, and then errors occur.

This is the line of the script where it's used:

```
$ver = '.'.filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$url).'.';
```

Is there another way to get the website root rather than server in the line above? Like just / at the top of the domain or subdomain, like where the RewriteBase would be defined?

Input is appreciated.

Comment: If this is changing to `/usr/local/apache/htdocs` you probably need to talk to your hosting company, soon. This could be the hosting provider changing something or something is configured very wrong. Bottom line, talk to your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to it explicitly in your script(s) would solve the problem as long as the doc_root doesn't change by default:

```
  $ver = '.'.filemtime('/home/username/public_html/'.$url).'.';
```

You should always have access to this directory as shared hosting structures don't usually change (unless they want to loose customers!). Let them know it's happening and ask why too.

Comment: Thank you for the input, and yeah, I did let them know. I use Bluehost, and I was talking to customer service explaining whatever structure they use is interfering every so often with programming trying to retrieve the root. They just continued to blame it on the script, and hid behind their "not helping with coding". Happen to know if there's an alternative PHP function that won't go so deep when acquiring the path?

Comment: You could try the approaches/answers mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952896/is-it-prefered-to-use-serverdocument-root-in-the-website - one of which is relative.

Comment: Am I using this correctly? I tried this and it breaks the script:
`$ver_id = '.'.filemtime(dirname(__FILE__).$ver_url).'.';`